# Олимпиадная задача на динамическое программирование

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада, динамическое-программирование

На сборах по программированию дали задачу, решение не прошу, но если у вас есть какие-либо идеи (на какую хотя бы тему эта задача) буду очень рад. Петя - программист, поэтому у него есть одно странное увлечение, он любит играть с массивами. **Перед игрой он выбирает число K**, после чего Петя может брать **НЕ МЕНЕЕ** чем K подряд идущих цифр и менять их (в массиве записаны лишь 0 и 1, мальчик нули меняет на единицы и обратно). Задача Пети сделать так, чтобы в массиве остались лишь нули, а ваша - найти самую большую K.
Пример:
010
Ответ:
2

Разбор:
Сначала Петя сделает массив 001, затем 111, а после 000 (он может это сделать ведь длина отрезка на котором он меняет цифры >= k).

Comment: А вы можете для данного K проверить, позволяет ли оно обнулить массив?

Comment: Если честно, нет :(

Comment: А какая асимптотика должна быть по данным K+n или k*n?

Answer (score 0):

Возьмем `K = количество_цифр - 1`.

Очевидно, что это дает свободно менять первую и последнюю цифру (можно поменять сначала весь массив кроме нее, а потом ее саму), а середина массива должна быть или из одних нулей, или из одних единиц.

Дальше должно быть просто.